# delete the middle child (@OneToMany and @ManyToOne relation) entity in Spring boot (parent -> middle child -> child)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have 3 entities:

```
@Entity
public class Province {
  @Id
  UUID id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="province", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  Set<District> districts;
}
```

And,

```
@Entity
public class District {
  @Id
  UUID id;
  @ManyToOne
  Province province;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="district", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  Set<Commune> communes;
}
```

and,

```
@Entity
public class Commune {
  @Id
  UUID id;
  @ManyToOne
  District district;
}
```

I tried to delete the root (`Province`) with this command `provinceRepository.deleteById(id)` and delete the child (`Commune`) with `@Modifying` and `@Transactional` annotations and `communeRepository.deleteById(id)` command with `@Query("DELETE FROM Commune c WHERE c.id = ?1")`, they work perfectly. But, when i tried to delete the middle one (`District`) by the flow of province, hibernate doesn't run the delete statement or throw `Cannot delete or update the parent row` when i used the commune's flow.

How can i delete the `District` ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So Basically the modification you have to make is
Change the fetch type from EAGER to LAZY
And after this It works completely fine.